# Java exam prep - Recursion task

Tags: java, recursion

This is my task:

Use recursion to find 13th member of an array where every member is multiplication of last two members minus the second member. First two members are 3 and 3.

This is what I came up with:

```
public class Zadatak2 {

    int array[] = {3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    public Zadatak2(){
        find13(2);
    }

    public int find13(int index){
        if (index == 13){
            System.out.println("Member 13: " + array[index-1]);
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            array[index] = array[index-1] * array[index-2] - array[1];
            System.out.println(index + " : " + array[index]);
            return find13(index + 1);
        } 
    }
}
```

Console output where I see index in array : value :

```
2 : 6
3 : 15
4 : 87
5 : 1302
6 : 113271
7 : 147478839
8 : 1947758222
9 : 465247871
10 : 818773103
11 : -459621106
12 : 383828239
Member 13: 383828239
```

But I am pretty sure I made a mistake or there is a better solution. Any help is  appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem you are looking to solve?

Comment: The fact that you got a negative number means that an int is too small for this.  Without checking anything else, I'd switch to a data type that has a larger maximum

Comment: This is my task:

Use recursion to find 13th member of an array where every member is multiplication of last two members minus the second member. First two members are 3 and 3.

Up there is my solution but I am pretty sure I made a mistake, as I said at the end

Comment: In general, stackoverflow is meant for looking to solve a specific error.  If you want someone to review your code, I'd use the codereview stackexchange

Comment: Kevin switching to double, output:
 Member 13: 4.17283635643594E90 ... oh I am sorry, I thought this would be ok since I always find these kinds of problems and solutions on stackoverflow

Comment: @KevinW. This question was not ready for CR because of the erroneous output. Had that issue (which you yourself pointed out to the OP) been solved *before* it was cross-posted, it would have worked. Unfortunately, this question ended up being closed on CR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin W. said in a comment, in the future, "if you want someone to review your code... use the codereview stackexchange". However, here are a few suggestions.

Firstly, as something to keep in mind, the problem you have is a lot like calculating the fibonacci sequence, and there are probably plenty of examples of using recursion to calculate members of that sequence.

Secondly, the way you built your recursive function makes it limited to being used only to find the 13th number in the sequence. You begin at the start of the sequence and work your way up to the 13th number, and what you are doing is basically an iterative solution to the problem with minor tweaks to make it work via recursion.

A better approach would be to generalize your function so that you can pass the sequence member number as a parameter, and the function will calculate it via recursion. The way to do this is to start at your target member number and through recursion, get the members required to make that member. This allows the function to be used to calculate any number in the sequence, not just the 13th number. It also has the added benefit that your code can be both shrunk and do more.

This is the code:

```
// index is the member number; it is 1 based e.g. index of 1 gives the first number in the sequence
int find(int index)
{
    if (index == 1 || index == 2)
        return 3;

    return (find(index - 1) * find(index - 2)) - find(2);
}
```

When solving problems with recursion, the method generally used is to start with the problem you want to solve and break it down (as shown in my code above), rather than start with subproblems to find the larger problem (as your code shows).

When applying recursion to a sequence, write out the mathematical definition of the sequence first, and that is what must be returned from the recursive function. For example, in your problem, the definition is

a[n] = (a[n-1] * a[n-2]) - a[2]

Now take a look at the solution I wrote. What I am returning is precisely this sequence definition, just in terms of the recursive function. The base case at the beginning of the function is simply the initial member(s) required to calculate the rest of the sequence. I encourage you to work the algorithm through on paper and play with it to see exactly what is happening.

As a final note, this algorithm is horrendous in terms of run time. There are three recursive calls per call to find(), which means that finding the 13th member is on the order of 3^13, which is exponential. Exponential algorithms are terrible algorithms, and should always be avoided.

If the recursion is examined closely you can see that in order to calculate a[n], the code calculates a[n-1] and a[n-2]. But in order to calculate a[n-1], a[n-2] and a[n-3] are both calculated, meaning that a[n-2] is calculated TWICE. This observation is very important because we only went down one level of recursion. There are a total of about 3^13 member calculations occurring when all there should be are 13 (for the 13 members). All of that time performing the same calculations millions of times is a horrendous waste and is what makes exponential algorithms so awful.

So what if we stored each of the members that the function calculates? This technique is called dynamic programming, and is where answers to subproblems are stored on the way to solving a larger problem so calculations are not performed multiple times. The solution implementing dynamic programming is:

```
// a variable that persists across function calls such as an instance field
int[] array = new int[20];    // just giving some extra memory in case you want to calculate other members
array[0] = -1;      //invalid member of the sequence since it is 1-based
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 3;

//set the rest of the numbers to values letting you know they have not been set/found/calculated yet
for (int i = 3; i < 20; i++)
{
    array[i] = -1;
}

// index is the member number; it is 1 based e.g. index of 1 gives the first number in the sequence
int find(int index)
{
    if (array[index] != -1)   //if already calculated that member, just return it
        return array[index];

    //store the answer
    array[index] = (find(index - 1) * find(index - 2)) - find(2);
    return array[index];
}
```

With this code, you can call find() for any number and it will calculate it for you, instead of just the 13th number.

Lastly, and most importantly, as Kevin W. pointed out in a comment, the presence of a negative number as a member means that you are getting numbers too big for ints. Luka Milosevic says that the 13th member is actually a number x10^90, which is too big for a long even. Doubles can work as long as you don't need more than 20 or so digits of precision, but because of at least 90 digits in the answer, doubles are not accurate enough. Fortunately Java has a class called BigInteger, which can store as large of numbers as you want, regardless of size. In order to obtain your answer, you probably have to use them, unless you want to do the math manually. The documentation for BigInteger is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Thank you so much ! After reading the task few more times I think what they meant by "minus the second" is basicly [index-2] ... then there is no need for biginteger ... anyways thank you so much for explaining everything, all clear now :)

Comment: by the way on code review they couldn't help me ... they need working code even if I said that the code is working ... anyways .. thank you so much !

Comment: basicly I had to take a look at how finding a fibonacci number using recursion works .. with your explanation and taking a look at simple fibonacci recursion .. got it all figured out now ...

Comment: @Luka Milosevic You may still need BigInteger. If you have the number 123456789123456789123456789123456789, a double will only capture about the first 20 digits and the rest will be unknown, yielding 123456789123456789000000000000000000, which would not be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a task you were assigned to do I would like to give you a hint only. In our case a recursive function would call itself with a lower argument and finally end with some defined values.

In our case the lower values `f(1)` and `f(2)` are already defined as `3`.

So `f(n) = f(n-1) * f(n-2) - f(2)` where `f(1) = 3` and `f(2) = 3`.

(If I understood the task right)

Now your job is to do the coding and find `f(13)`.

Does it help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time ... but .. that is the part I do understand and the part I think I did ... and I get that 13th member .. what I would like to know is if my code is ok with programming and java standards .. i don't know how to explain what I want in any other way .. what I would like to know is if the way I called my method with passing it index 2 is ok .. if my logic is ok .. if the way I defined the array is ok ... If that is something that could be asked here .. I tried on code review .. they said they can't help me neither...